# Apk file crashed implemented by buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I am new at buildozer and kivy. I have implemented a layout in kivy and tried to implement apk using buildozer, apk has been created but crashes every time I run it on an android device. I have built some pages before but this page is the only one that crashes. I am not sure about the reason for this, is this for because I am using box layout or fixed height or using scroll view?

```
RootWidget:
RelativeLayout:
    id: user_container
    size:(root.width,root.height)
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .98823529411,.98823529411,.98823529411,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    pos: (root.width * .011, root.height *.011)
    ScrollView:
        size:self.size
        pos: (root.width * .01, root.height *.001)
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            size:(740,1200)
            size_hint:1,None
            spacing:20
            #pos: (root.width * .050, root.height *.053)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .98823529411,.98823529411,.98823529411,1 
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'horizontal'
                spacing:20
                BoxLayout:
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: .949,.976,.917, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    Label:
                        text:"choose one or moro answer"
                        color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                        font_size:'17sp'
                    Label:
                        text:"0 is even number"
                        color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                        font_size:'17sp'
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:

                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/checked_checkbox_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-13
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer one'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:

                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/unchecked_checkbox_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-13
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer two'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:

                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/unchecked_checkbox_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-13
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer three'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:

                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/checked_checkbox_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-13
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer four'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: .949,.976,.917, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    Label:
                        text:"choose one or moro answer"
                        color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                        font_size:'17sp'
                    Label:
                        text:"0 is even number"
                        color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                        font_size:'17sp'
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:
                            group:'two'
                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/checked_radio_button_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-11
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer one'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:
                            group:'two'
                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/unchecked_radio_button_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-11
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer two'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:
                            group:'two'
                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/unchecked_radio_button_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-11
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer three'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:
                            group:'two'
                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/checked_radio_button_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-11
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer four'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'horizontal'
                spacing:20
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: .949,.976,.917, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    Label:
                        text:"choose one or moro answer"
                        color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                        font_size:'17sp'
                    Label:
                        text:"0 is even number"
                        color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                        font_size:'17sp'
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:

                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/checked_checkbox_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-13
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer one'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:

                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/checked_checkbox_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-13
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer two'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:

                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/unchecked_checkbox_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-13
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'answer three'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        Label:
                            size_hint_x:.5
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.2
                            on_active:

                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/checked_checkbox_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                                x: self.parent.x-13
                                height:50
                        Label:
                            text:'other'
                            size_hint_x:.3
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp'
                        TextInput:
                            size_hint_x:.5
                            foreground_color: .26,.26,.3,1
                            hint_text_color:(.501,.756,.172, 1)
                            font_size:'17sp'
                            multiline: True
                            hint_text:'suggestion'
                            padding_y:35
                            height:50
                            background_normal: "resource/images/form_screen/text_input_box_green.jpg"
                            background_active: "resource/images/form_screen/text_input_box_red.jpg"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: .949,.976,.917, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    Label:
                        text:'true/false'
                        color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                        font_size:'17sp'    
                    Label:
                        text:'O is even number'
                        color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                        font_size:'17sp' 
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        Label:
                            text:'false'
                            size_hint_x:.25
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                            font_size:'17sp' 
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.25
                            on_active:
                            group:'true'
                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/cross_not_ok_red_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 125
                                x: self.parent.x-4
                                height:50

                        Label:
                            text:'true'
                            size_hint_x:.25
                            color:.501,.756,.172, 1
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint_x:.25
                            on_active:
                            group:'true'
                            Image:                  
                                source: "resource/images/icon/check_ok_green_32.png"
                                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 125
                                x: self.parent.x-4
                                height:50
```

Comment: It looks like you already have 3 suspects that may be breaking your program. Have you tried removing all of them? Did it still break? Then there's something else to be looked into. If it works, try adding those three options one by one and see when it starts breaking again. That way, you will either understand the problem and fix it yourself or at least be able to edit our some irrelevant code from your question

Comment: i have tried without scroll or without fixed height still it has crashed

Comment: Have you tried `buildozer android deploy run logcat` to see the logcat output?

Comment: @tanziinafatiima: Your kv file showed that there are two root widgets i.e. `RootWidget:` and `RelativeLayout:`

Comment: I think it's a resolution issue 
1200*740 I think is not supported by most phones